# Unescape HTML in etherpad lite

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, etherpad

Hi I am working on an app that adds some features to etherpad lite. I want to add some html elements to etherpad pad so i need to unescape the html and display it on the pad. I was just curious to know if it is possible. Just for the record I am using ruby api in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which way it is you want to go, but to convert to from escaped characters in JavaScript you use either `decodeURIComponent()` or `encodeURIComponent()`.

That would take `hey you` and encode to `hey%20you` or decode the other way.